# Embedding data in resource files

Tags: windows, resources

Due to some brain damage, (either in windows or in me), there appears to be no API to get the size of a windows resource produced by LoadResource.  The return type is HANDLE, but it's not a real handle, and GlobalSize does not work on it.

So absent the API, I need to embed my blobs in some simple format that will
wrap them with their length.  Surely there must be a utility somewhere that 
rewrites a file as a length, followed by the contents of the file, or some
such trivial encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to your question as to a helper for the work-around, but the API is not missing.

When you called [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you passed in the module handle and a HRSRC handle.
If you call [SizeOfResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the same arguments, it returns the size of the resource.